# Disabilities tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

How would you handle a disabilities tag for questions on blindness/deafness? I mean that eventually someone is going to want to create it anyway.

Answer (score 10):

### Conditions are not Disabilities

If a [disabilities](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disabilities) tag were to be created it would need clear usage guidance. Conditions and effects such as those applied by the *blindness/deafness* spell in D&D 5e should not be considered disabilities. We should also be clear whether it is referring characters or players with disabilities.

However my belief is that we should not be creating tags pre-emptively. If questions arise where this or a similar tag would be beneficial then it can be created. We shouldn't try to predefine use-cases that don't exist. It is possible that the use-case for this tag exists, in which case we should look at the list of questions it should apply to and define it based on that list.

Answer (score 10):

#### Use existing tags.

We already have a tag for blindness, [blind](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blind), and have historically used the tag [hearing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hearing) for questions about in-game deafness.

For out-of-game issues relating to these things, use [accessibility](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility). Existing tags have you covered.

Comment: Huh... I am surprise we lack a [tag:flaws] tag or similar...